# Waiting for a prompt on an exe

Tags: python

I have a executable that lets me talk to a temperature controller. When I double-click the exe (SCPI-CLI.exe) it will open up a command window with text "TC_CLI>". I can then type my commands and talk to my controller: eg: `TC:COMM:OPEN:SER 8`

When I use the `subprocess.Popen` like this

```
import subprocess
text = 'tc:comm:open:ser 8'
proc = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TC_SCPI\\lib\\SCPI-CLI.exe'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(text)
proc.stdin.close()
result = proc.stdout.read()
print(result)
```

the SCPI-CLI.exe will open up, but will not show me the > prompt. What am I doing wrong here? It will hang at the `proc.stdin.write(text)`.
I am a newbie to sub-process.

Comment: Depending upon what you need to do (and what platform you are on) an [expect script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) may be another way to go.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned: Using Windows 8.1, Python 2.7, Pyscripter 2.6

Comment: You mentioned that the prompt goes out first, so you must read the program's stdout first - that's probably what it is waiting on.

Comment: Can you upload and send the binary so i can give a try ?

Comment: It won't show the prompt, you have just captured that.  It could be that the exe is using the WIN32 console APIs, not stdin and stdout.  Do you have the source code?

Comment: @cdarke -No I dont have the source code. Any pointers to where I should start looking into? Will do some digging of my own as well..Also, what did you mean by it wont show the prompt you have just captured that..The result output is ending in TC_CLI> which is the prompt..Did not understand, sorry

Comment: You said that it did not show the prompt, but then you say the result output does have the prompt.

Comment: @cdarke : The stdout.read() string has the prompt, but the window that opens up does not.The window shows the path of the exe as the title of the window, but the prompt itself does not show up.

Comment: Of course the prompt does not show, you are reading it.  It is going into your buffer *instead* of going to the console - the program only writes the prompt once.

Comment: @cdarke: If I just say
        p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TC_SCPI\\lib\\SCPI-CLI.exe'])
it will open up the SCPI-CLI.exe and will wait at the prompt. But since I have not given the stdin argument, I cannot pass in the text command at this point. How do I do that? I tried p.sendsignal(text), did not work. 
If I do:
        subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TC_SCPI\\lib\\SCPI-CLI.exe']stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
the command window will come up without the prompt.

Comment: So, have you dropped the `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`?

Comment: @cdarke: Yes, just wanted to see what would happen.

Comment: I can't try out this program for you, sorry. I'm not on Windows right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add "\n" to your string, that way you send the <kbd>enter</kbd> key.
Also please try to add pipe to stderr also and see if it display any error (or maybe it use stderr instead of stdout for displaing messages)
One more thing, is a good idea to wait for this program to exit before reading the results.

Try this:

```
import subprocess
import time
import os

text = b'tc:comm:open:ser 8\nexit\n'
proc = subprocess.Popen(['SCPI-CLI.exe'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

out,err = proc.communicate(text)
print(out.decode())
```

Comment: Tried that, did \r\n, \r, \n..no luck.

Comment: @SrinivasLyer Can i have the binary file so i can give a try ?

Comment: Let me know if you are able to access this. Zipped up the contents of the lib folder which has the exe and the other DLLs:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByskHAf6ibwGS21manFlcllrZXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SrinivasIyer It was the read(). The read was blocking your program until the EOF which is received when the process close. You can make read(10) to see that a part of message is received.

Comment: Where have you used the read(), is it the  out.decode(). And what is the \nexit\n at the end of the text? Thanks a lot for helping out on this..

Comment: @SrinivasIyer \nexit\n means "enter" exit "enter". this send exit command to ur program. And for read / write from / to the process i use "communicate", which sends the command (text) and read the stdout into out and stderr into out. Do not forget tu vote-up and accept this answer it this helped.

Comment: @ I changed the text to: text = b'tc:comm:open:ser 8\ncont:spt 75\nexit()\n' and it now works!! Thanks a tonne for the help

Comment: Did that..Let me know

Comment: @SrinivasIyer [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) and [this](http://i.imgur.com/kygEP.png)

Comment: Did that. however, vote up says require 15+ reputation. marked the answer as useful though. hope it helps/

Comment: @SrinivasIyer Thanks you very much. If you need more help just ask :D